# jquery get each tr from result data

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    timeout: 30000,
    url: '' + baseurl + '/Company/ManageWorkReport/GetGroup',
    data: { 
        groupId: value, 
        needActiveOn: activeOn 
    },    
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // ...
```

`data` are:

```
<tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr>
```

I would like to loop `result` over each `tr`. Normally I do it like this:

```
$("#myTable tbody tr").each(function() {});
```

However I don't know how to do it with the `data` variable.

Comment: Not much of an explanation of relation between data and rows. Explain objective in more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the request you're making returns a HTML `table` element to the `data` variable, you can do this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        $(data).filter('tbody tr').each(function() {
            // do something with each row...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: data are just: <tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr>

Comment: In that case you need to use `filter()`, not `find()`. I updated my answer for you.